# HasMany - сохранить данные по ассоциации в cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

помогите решить проблему.
Есть две таблицы ***business_departments*** и ***companies***, связь **hasMany.**

Мне нужно изменить список компаний из бизнес департамента. Код сгенерирован при помощи **bake** и далее модифицирован.

**Controller.**

```
$businessDepartment = $this->BusinessDepartments->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Companies']
]);
$companies = $this->BusinessDepartments->Companies->find('list')->where([
    'Companies.active' => true, 
    'Companies.type IS NOT' => 'service', 
    'OR' => [
        'business_department_id IS NULL',
        'business_department_id' => $id
    ]
])->distinct('Companies.id');
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    debug($this->request->getData());
    $businessDepartment = $this->BusinessDepartments->patchEntity($businessDepartment, $this->request->getData(), ['associated' => ['Companies']]);
    debug($businessDepartment);
    if ($this->BusinessDepartments->save($businessDepartment)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The business department has been saved.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('The business department could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
$this->set(compact('businessDepartment', 'companies'));
```

**Entity.**

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'name' => true,
    'companies' => true
];
```

**Table**

```
$this->hasMany('Companies', [
    'foreignKey' => 'business_department_id',
    // Tried it
    /*'dependent' => true,
    'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
    'saveStrategy' => 'replace'*/
]);
```

**template.**

```
echo $this->Form->control('companies._ids', ['options' => $companies, 'multiple' => true, 'class' => 'multiple-find']);
```

При первом добавлении компаний сохранение происходит нормально, но когда я пробую изменить список компаний или сохранить без изменений, получаю сообщение об ошибке.

Могу ли я изменить список компании с помощью `_ids` или необходимо писать свой код?

**Ошибки и Debugs:**

`debug($this->request->getData())`

```
[
    'name' => 'Office',
    'companies' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '21',
            (int) 1 => '29'
        ]
    ]
]
```

При редактировании (не первом), patchEntity вместо того что бы найти записи в таблице ***companies*** и модифицировать их, пытаеться создать новую сущность. Вот фрагменты скриншотов [`debug($businessDepartment)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaNnd.png) и [страница с ошибкой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvwhA.png)

Спасибо, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: зачем вы отдельным запросом грузите компании? сразу `->contain(['Companies' => function($q){ $q->find('list')->where(....) }])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-то пригодится!

> you have validation errors in your company related data, thats why you
>   cant save it, if you want to just use `_ids` as save try clearing
>   `companies` field in your `$businessDepartment` i.e.
>
> ```
> $businessDepartment->unsetProperty('companies');
> ```
>
> before `patchEntity`
>
> [Graziel](https://discourse.cakephp.org/u/Graziel)